# How to execute a callback function after ajax content has been loaded into a newly added jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Jquery UI tabs has an add event which is triggered immediately after a tab is added.  In this example, when you click a button a new tab is added and it is selected.

I'm adding dynamic content using ajax in the following way:

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    add: function (event, ui){
        var lastIndex = $("#tabs").tabs("length")-1;
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", lastIndex);
    }
});

function createTab(phpFile){
    $tabs.tabs("add", phpFile, "Tab Title"); 
}

$("button").on('click', function (){                   
    var url = "search.php?term=someRandomString";
    createPlaySongTab(url);      
});
```

My goal is to have the newly added content fade into the panel like so

```
    add: function (event, ui){
        $(ui.panel).hide();
        var lastIndex = $("#tabs").tabs("length")-1;
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", lastIndex);
        $(ui.panel).fadeIn(1000);
    }
```

Let's say my .php looked like this

```
<?php sleep(1); echo 'hello world!';?>
```

In this case the content would not fade in at all since duration of the fade was `fadeIn(1000)` and the add event is triggered immediately after the tab is added, not after the .php file is done loading.  How can I get the content to fade in after the content has completely loaded?

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for, but if you use an AJAX get call, you can call your fadeIn in the success function.

Comment: Thanks Kris, I was using the AJAX get call before I incorporated jquery ui tabs, but I was told this particularly method of parsing the output of an ajax get call into a newly created tab was preferred when using jquery ui tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try load event. This event should fire once content of remote tab was loaded.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   load: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is jquery function for it ajaxcomplete(); google it, hope this helps
$('#element').ajaxcomplete(function(){ your stuff//});

Comment: I took a look at that function.  It seems similar to what Kris suggested in a comment to my original post. I'm not sure how I can implement your suggestion since the ajax call is being done through the jquery ui tabs add method http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-add.  I would appreciate working example of what you're describing in context to my question.

Comment: if you are binding your ajax call to $('#element') then just add $('#element'.ajaxcomplete...) function anywhere in your script it will automaticaly get called once ajax is done, if you are not calling ajax from any element , then do something tricky like get a returning value from your dynamic function any element <span class='animNow'></span> and add a function once $('.animNow').ready(function(){your stuff and $(document).find('.animNow').remove();}) // something like that