# jquery tabs not displaying ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm getting the data to client, but the data does not show up in the tabs ?? Here is what I'm getting in **response** to the ajax request sent on clicking a tab:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 196
Date: Wed, 23 May 2012 08:57:02 GMT

{
    "footerPkg": {
        "hotelRoomPrice": 1,
        "idHolidayPackage": 1,
        "idHolidayPackageVariant": 1,
        "idOriginCity": 1,
        "itineraryHeader": "Header",
        "miscPrice": 0,
        "name": "name",
        "occupancyType": "TWIN",
        "variantPrice": 10
    }
}
```

In my jsp, I am using this to create tabs:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%-- <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%> --%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link
    href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            dataType: "json",
            success : function(data, status) {
                alert(data.footerPkg.name);
            }
        }
    });
  });
  </script>

<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body onload="alert('body load');">

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="getJsonResult.action?idPkg=1">Tab 0</a></li>
            <li><a href="getJsonResult.action?idPkg=1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="HelloWorld.jsp">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

However, I see nothing in the tabs content. Even Homepage.jsp which is plain text is not showing up in tab 3.

This is what it looks like:

[image: empty tabs]

Comment: remove comma after ajaxOptions completes.

Comment: @PriyankPatel That didn't help either!

Comment: r u loading js file for tabs ??

Comment: @PriyankPatel Yes. I can see the tabs with no content. Updated question with included js

Comment: @PriyankPatel I had earlier pasted code snippet for reference. However, I replaced that with my current file now.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a callback function after the data comes back to your ajax success method. The callback is necessary to let the jquery ui know that there is new data to process.

This could be a duplicate of this question.

[Callback after ajax loading a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740652/callback-after-ajax-loading-a-tab)

Here is another one with a clear example of the load function needed

[How to execute a callback function after ajax content has been loaded into a newly added jquery ui tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336520/how-to-execute-a-callback-function-after-ajax-content-has-been-loaded-into-a-new)

Comment: The control reaches the function in success event of ajaxOptions and I can also see the data in alert. But this data is not being displayed in the div tab. Do I need to call load explicitly ?

Comment: Updated my question with an image

Comment: Dex, yes, in my understanding it is necessary to trigger the update using the load.

Comment: I feel I am missing something trivial here. Can you give me a simple snippet on how to trigger the update using load to "actually" get it to display the data ?

Comment: ok, lets look at a different route here, how are you viewing the json being received by the browser? Firebug? fiddler? If you can put that exact text into JSONlint.com and test the json that would be helpful, don't know if that header info should be showing up in the return data. Also, try using the script debugger in your browser of choice. I know when my data is not showing up, it's either a script error or a JSON formatting error.

Comment: Yes, I am viewing the data with Fiddler and run it by JSONlint.com to verify its good. They all checkout fine. Header returns status 200. Everything is there, it's just that the tabs won't show the data :(

Comment: What do you mean by script errors ? Chrome shows no javascript errors in its console if that's what you mean..

Comment: Yes, the chrome console is what I meant. Try adding a title to your li>href like so:
            <li><a title="tab1" href="getJsonResult.action?idPkg=1">Tab 0</a></li>                                         http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tabs-data-not-loading-into-tabs-area

Comment: If that doesn't work, the way I go is to create the tabs and have them point to a div, then use a $.ajax call and on success update that div with the data from the ajax call, and just catch the tab clicks to load appropriate data. I can supply a sample if this is the route you intend to go, I can edit the answer above for you.

Comment: yea, so this is my temporary solution. I specify the title to each tab and then in my `success` handler, I manually update the div with the json data! I'll post my code here so you can also take a look at it.

Comment: AWESOME! Yeah, that's how I usually make the tabs work with AJAX. Was trying to get it working your way, since that was the direction you were on also because the JQuery docs say it's that simple. I'm happy you got.